# how to increase autocomplete combo text element width in form in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

It looks like in edit and add forms all field have fixed width.

I tried to increase edit/add from width but input elements widths are still
too small, smaller than column widths defined in colmodel.

How to increase those widths or make them the same as defined in colmodel ?
Label column windth is too big. How to decrease label column width so that 
its width is equal to largest label text width ?

**Update 1**

colmodel contains autocomplete combobox

```
{name:"AutocompleteWidthIssue",
edittype:"custom",
editoptions:{
    maxlength:54,
    size:54,
    custom_element:function(value, options) {
    return combobox_element(value, options,'17','test','Summak','Tululiik')
    },
    custom_value:combobox_value
},
editable:true,
width:39,
fixed:true
},


function combobox_element(value, options, width, colName, entity, andmetp) {
    var elemStr = '<div><input style="width:' + width + 'px" value="' + value + '"/>' +
'<button type="button" style="height:20px;width:20px;vertical-align:center;margin-left:-2px" tabindex=-1/></div>';
    var newel = $(elemStr)[0];

    input.autocomplete({
        source: 'Grid/GetLookupList'
    }
);

    $("button", newel)
    .button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'} })
       });

    return newel;
}
```

In inline edit mode code above renders combobox with correct width,
size:54 is ignored.

How to increase width of autocomplete text input element in form edit/add mode only, so that its text element width takes width from size or other attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `editoptions: {size:35, maxlength: 45}`. Probably it's what you need. It should increase the size of the input elements for the corresponding column to be able to enter approximate 35 characters without scrolling the data. The input of more as 45 characters will be prohibited. It can be that you will need to increase the default value 300 of the [width](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) parameter of Edit/Add form to be able to show all input elements of the form without horizontal scrolling.

No additional setting to long labels should be done. The form consist on the table which increase the column width automatically.

**UPDATED**: You can use the `display:inline-block` for the parent `<span class="FormElement">` which enclose the HTML fragment returned by the `custom_element`. The following code

```
function combobox_element(value, width) {
    var elemStr = '<div>' +
                  '<input class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ' +
                  'style="vertical-align:top;width:' +  width + 'px" value="' +
                  value + '"/>' +
                  '<button class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-right ui-button-icon"' +
                  ' style="height:22px;width:22px;" tabindex="-1" /></div>',
        newel = $(elemStr)[0];

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(newel).parent().css({display: "inline-block"})
                .parent().css({'padding-bottom': 0});
        $('input:first', newel).autocomplete({
            source: 'Grid/GetLookupList'
        });

        $("button", newel).button({
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'},
            text: false
        });
    }, 50);

    return newel;
}
```

will produce

[image]

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithFormEditData1.htm).

Comment: Thank you. This does not work with custom_element. How to increase autocomplete combo text input element width in form edit/add modes only? I updated question about this and provided code sample

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution changes input width in inline edit mode also. How to increase input width only in form, not in inline edit ?

Comment: @Andrus: You can set in the `custom_element` function the width for the inline editing and adjust the width inside of `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm` for the form editing.

Comment: thank you. ColModel is defined as `{name:"WideComboInEdit,edittype:custom,editoptions:{size:54,custom_element:function(value, options) {
return combobox_element(value, options,'17','Tululiik2_nimetus','Summak','Tululiik')}
,custom_value:combobox_value
},editable:true,width:39},` how to force text element to use specified size:54 in form edit/add only? Currently size:54 is ignored. width:39 is used in form also. Is is resonable to create jquery setter which assigns size values to input elements in combos?

Comment: @Andrus: In case of custom editing **you (your implementation of the `custom_element` function)** should do all this manually. The `options` parameter can be use to get the `editoptions`. The `width` of the `input` element you set explicitly (see ''17'' in your example and `250` in my demo). About creating of setter and so on you should decide such problems yourself depend on the context (other requirements of your project) .

Comment: thank you. custom_element function is called in both inline and in form edit. How to determine inside this function from which edit mode it is called for how to specifiy differnt function or parameter for different edit modes ?

Comment: @Andrus: the easiest way to detect the editing mode inside of `custom_element` is to examine the `options`. If `options.id === options.name` we are in the form editing mode (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L429)). In inline editing mode the `options.id` will be constructed as `rowid + '_' + options.name` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L59)), so `options.id !== options.name`.

Comment: excellent, it works. I marked it as answer and upvoted responses. I removed `class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-right ui-button-icon"` and noticed no difference in both edit modes. Why those classes are reqired, jquery ui button() probably adds them. It works also without setTimeout() call. Maybe hint in jqGrid docs about requiring settimeout is obsolete, is it ok to use without setTimeout() ?

Comment: setTimeout causes rows out of sync iuuse with frozen columns as discussed in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/52  is setTimeout() in this code still required in free-jqgrid with latest jquery and jquery-ui or can it removed ? Otherwize ` $grid.trigger("jqGridResetFrozenHeights");` needs to be added inside setTimeout() also

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, but the answer is about **form editing** and issue 52 is about **inline editing**. You can easy move the initialization of the element the element (from `setTimeout` part) in `dataInit`. I think that you will don't need to use any `setTimeout` more. If you would do need it, but only in **form editing**, You can just test whether `.parent().parent().hasClass("jqgrow")` or to use `options.mode` (I'll most the changes today). So I'm sure that you can remove `setTimeout` at least in case of usage inline editing.